# MCP23008 Python Input Handler

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, mcp3008, circuitpython

How do I declare a Python callback handler method on a [MCP23008](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21919e.pdf) input pin?
[This Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/using-mcp23008-mcp23017-with-circuitpython?view=all), which uses [CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/index.html) shows how to read input from the extended GPIO pin on the MCP23008, but does not appear to have a callback/interrupt handler interface:

```py
import board
import busio
import digitalio

from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23008 import MCP23008

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp = MCP23008(i2c)
pin1 = mcp.get_pin(1)
pin1.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
print(f"Value = {}", pin1.value)
```

I want to treat the GPIO pins on the MCP23008 just as I would treat GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi, and bind a callback handler when the input changes, as in this example that uses [`RPi.GPIO`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-gpio-python/):

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

def my_callback(channel):
    print('callback was called! This is what I want to do!')

GPIO.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596063/237225))

I am currently using these versions, but I am open to other libraries.

```
adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice 5.1.1      
adafruit-circuitpython-mcp230xx  2.5.1
```

Comment: Perhaps try these: (1) Using an MCP23017 with a Pi Pico [SOLVED] - rpi.org.forum 2021jun01
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=313070#p1872514

(2) Raspberry Pi Pico MCP23017 Library - GitHub 2021feb01
https://github.com/adamboardman/pico-mcp23017